# python dict parameter and or kwargs

Tags: python, dictionary, keyword-argument

the following code inside a function def seems to me to be unwieldy. Is there a better way to conditionally prefer one parameter over a dict. This came from some impedance mismatch between robotframework which does not (IMO) have a satisfactory handle on kwargs:

```
def get_passwd(input_dict=None, **kwargs):
    pswd = None
    if input_dict:
        if input_dict and input_dict.get('passphrase_confirm'):
            pswd = input_dict['passphrase_confirm']
        elif kwargs.get('passphrase_confirm'):
            pswd = kwargs['passphrase_confirm']
    if not pswd:
        # here because there was no password_confirm or no input_dict, we look again in kwargs
        if 'passphrase_confirm' in kwargs and kwargs['passphrase_confirm']:
            pswd = kwargs['passphrase_confirm']
        elif input_dict and 'passphrase' in input_dict and input_dict['passphrase_confirm']:
            pswd = input_dict['passphrase']
        elif 'passphrase' in kwargs and kwargs['passphrase']:
            pswd = kwargs['passphrase']
    return pswd
```

Comment: It's interesting that you mention robotframework, but don't show how you are using this function from the framework. If you could show an example of this "impedence mismatch" perhaps there's a better solution than to accept either a dict or kwargs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the simplest solution is to merge the two dictionaries, then just use the `get` method on the result. If I understand your logic correctly (and I'm not sure I do...), you want the value of "passphrase_confirm" if it exists in one of the dictionaries, and if it doesn't, you want "passphrase". Also, if it's in both, you want the one from `input_dict`.

I think this does what you want, and is much easier to understand than your original code:

```
def get_passwd(input_dict=None, **kwargs):
    kwargs = kwargs if input_dict is None else dict(kwargs.items() + input_dict.items())
    if "passphrase_confirm" in kwargs:
        return kwargs["passphrase_confirm"]
    else:
        return kwargs.get("passphrase", None)
```

Comment: I might even just do `return kwargs.get('passphrase_confirm') or kwargs.get('passphrase')`. It looks like the OP wants to ignore empty *or* missing `passphrase_confirm`.

Answer (score 1):

Following msudder's suggestion, you could merge the dictionaries (the default and the kwargs), and then get the answer from the merged dictionary.

More info on merging [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38990/1096146).   The syntax looks like: `merged = dict(kwargs.items() + input_dict.items())`, where the "winning" dictionary comes last.

Answer (score 0):

So you want pwd to be (in preference order) :

- `input_dict['passphrase_confirm']`
- `kwargs['passphrase_confirm']`
- `input_dict['passphrase']`
- `kwargs['passphrase']`

where `input_dict` may be None

You should write :

```
def get_passwd(input_dict=None, **kwargs):
    if input_dict and ('passphrase_confirm' in input_dict):
        pwd = input_dict['passphrase_confirm']
    elif 'passphrase_confirm' in kwargs:
        pwd = kwargs['passphrase_confirm']
    elif input_dict and ('passphrase' in input_dict):
        pwd = input_dict['passphrase']
    elif 'passphrase' in kwargs:
        pwd = kwargs['passphrase']
    else:
        pwd = None
    return pwd
```

That does the same than your original code (strict respect of preference order), has less redundance (if input_dict: if input_dict and ...) and is (I hope) more pythonic

Answer (score -1):

Change signature default for input dict and then you can remove all tests on input_dict to simply use dict.get making

```
def get_passwd(input_dict={}, **kwargs):
    pswd = None
    if input_dict.get('passphrase_confirm'):
        pswd = input_dict['passphrase_confirm']
    elif kwargs.get('passphrase_confirm'):
        pswd = kwargs['passphrase_confirm']
    if not pswd:
        # here because there was no password_confirm so use passphrase
        if input_dict.get('passphrase'):
            pswd = input_dict['passphrase']
        elif kwargs.get('passphrase'):
            pswd = kwargs.get('passphrase')
    return pswd
```

Comment: Mutable default is a common source of bugs, don't do it unless you know what you are writing. See http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/